# Using renameTo on File changes the content

Tags: java, android, path, directory

```
File dir = new File(getFilesDir(), "dir1");
dir.renameTo(new File(getFilesDir(), "dir2");
Log.d("Number of files:", dir.listFiles().length);
```

Suppose /dir1/ contains 5 files. This code will print 0.However, if I change the code to`

```
File dir = new File(getFilesDir(), "dir1");
dir.renameTo(new File(getFilesDir(), "dir2");
dir = new File(getFilesDir(), "dir2");
Log.d("Number of files:", dir.listFiles().length);
```

it will print the correct value: 5. Is there a reason for that? It looks like dir does not link to the same directory after I use renameTo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that in your first code `dir` is still pointing to the directory `dir1` and not `dir2`.

However, in the following code:

```
File dir = new File(getFilesDir(), "dir1");
dir.renameTo(new File(getFilesDir(), "dir2");
dir = new File(getFilesDir(), "dir2");
Log.d("Number of files:", dir.listFiles().length);
```

`dir` is now pointing to `dir2`, and thus you got the correct value.

I'll suggest you to avoid using Java's File.renameTo() since it is problematic, especially on Windows. As the API documentation says:

> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently
>   platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a
>   file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it
>   might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname
>   already exists. The return value should always be checked to make sure
>   that the rename operation was successful.

You can use apache.commons.io library, which includes FileUtils.moveFile() or also the Files.move() method in JDK 7.